# Actually opening spyder IDE

Tags: python, ide, spyder

I've been trying to follow instructions on [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases) and [here](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html) to install spyder.

I downloaded the Source Code zip file from the first link because that's what I believe is the dmg installer. I don't know what to do with any of the files in the zip file once I download them though.

I already have pip3 installed so I used the command

```
pip3 install -U spyder
```

When I run the commmand

```
/User/Downloads/spyder-3.2.8/scripts/spyder
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/User/Downloads/spyder-3.2.8/scripts/spyder", line 2, in <module>
    from spyder.app import start
ImportError: No module named spyder.app
```

To my understanding, spyder is supposed to be a python IDE that I am expecting to look [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vqaY.png)

I'm just trying to get the IDE running so that I can write my program within it to help me program easier. The only IDE i've used before is eclipse so maybe I'm not thinking of an IDE the right way, but I'm expecting something kind of like eclipse.

Comment: The error cannbe raised if it is not installed properly or if there is something named `spyder` or `spyder.py` in your working dir.

Comment: @KlausD. The error isn't what my main problem, it's just some information that might be helpful. The main problem is not knowing what to do with the downloaded source code and not knowing how to actually open spyder.

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) I think our installation instructions are quite clear, but I repeat them here for you again:

> If you are new to Python or the Scientific Python ecosystem, we **strongly** recommend you to install and use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download). It comes with Spyder and all its dependencies, along with the most important Python scientific libraries (i.e. Numpy, Pandas, Matplotlib, IPython, etc) in a single, easy to use environment.

After installing Anaconda, you need to open the Anaconda Navigator (using Spotlight) and run Spyder from there. Another option is to open `Terminal.app` and run `spyder` or `spyder3` there too.

You don't need to have our source code at all to use Spyder because it is installed by Anaconda or pip.

Finally, I don't know what Python version you used to run `pip3 install -U spyder`, but you should really remove what you installed with it and use Anaconda instead. As we said in our installation instructions too:

> We also support pip, but please be aware that pip installations are for advanced users with good knowledge of all Spyder dependencies.

This clearly seems to be not your case.